# How to add yourself to sudoers list?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, root, apt-get

I was trying to install a package using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm
```

But I'm prompted with

```
nish is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I tried to add myself to sudoers list in /etc/sudoers. But to do that I need to be logged in as root user.

using the command "sudo su" again prompts "nish is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."
Please cold someone help me out here.
Thanks

Comment: So, do you have another account that can sudo? If not, you'll have to ask your system administrator.

Comment: Another way..Try `su` and enter root's password (of course, if you're an admin). But that only works on some distributions by default as the root password is locked. Try using `sudo` with a user you created during the installation, it should have the permissions by default to run `sudo`

Comment: @slhck : Thanks, I logged in to another account and it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is the intended behavior. If you are not in the sudoers list, you should not be able to add yourself to, because on a multiuser system restricted users should not be able to gain full access. If you have the root password you could do

```
su root
```

to switch user to root and then add yourself to the sudoers list.